# Not sure if this sentence reads correctly

Tags: commas

I'm not sure if this sentence reads correctly?

**All your equipment, plant and tool needs from one place delivered on time.**

Should there be a comma after place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic, but if this is an advertising slogan for a plant hire company it sounds OK. The comma might make the meaning more obvious.

Comment: I would additionally suggest including an Oxford comma after plant to make the sentence even clearer. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

Comment: I would put a comma after  *place*,  and maybe one after *needs*.

Comment: Nope, it does not. It is not a sentence, because there is no verb.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm new to the forum and I'm just looking for a resource to ask questions and help me improve. Whilst the sentence is from a 500 word document I'm working on, I hope it doesn't come across as proofreading as that is not my intention. I just needed to query the one sentence as it didn't seem to read right but others thought it did. It seems like a comma after place would be better. Thanks.

Comment: Dear close-voters: Please familiarize yourself with the text of the close messages. This question is clearly ***not*** a request for proofreading, but does "*focus on something in particular that you are unsure about*", just as the close message requires. In this case, the thing in particular is the placement of a comma. Sorry for the bother Danny :)